# Reducing the number of used clauses using proof goal in Z3

Tags: z3, smt, theorem-proving

I am experimenting with optimizing the use of Z3 for proving facts about a first-order theory. Currently, I specify a first-order theory in Python, ground the quantifiers there and send all the clauses along with the negation of the proof goal to Z3. I have the following idea that I hope could optimize the outcome: I only want to send the formulas in the theory to Z3 that are *relevant* to the proof goal. I will not discuss this concept in detail, but I think the intuition is simple: my theory is a conjunction of formulas, and I only want to send conjuncts that can possibly affect the truth value of the proof goal.

My question is the following: can this lead to an improvement in efficiency, or does Z3 already use a similar method? I would guess not, because I don't think that Z3 always assumes that the last assertion is the proof goal, so it has no way of optimizing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, removing irrelevant facts can make a big difference. Suppose that we have a unsatisfiable formula of the form `F_1 and F_2 and (not G)`. Moreover, let us assume that `F_1 and (not G)` is unsatisfiable, and `F_2` is satisfiable. `F_2` is what you call irrelevant. If there is a cheap way to remove `F_2` before sending the formulat to Z3, it will probable make a big difference.

Z3 has heuristics for "ignoring" irrelevant facts, but they are just heuristics. For our example, the worst case scenario is a `F_2` that is really hard for Z3 to satisfy. Z3 is essentially trying to build an interpretation/solution that satisfies the input formula (the formula `F_1 an F_2 and (not G)` in our working example). A formula is unsatisfiable when Z3 can show it is impossible to build the interpretation. In practice, the formula `F_2` is irrelevant for Z3 only if it can quickly show it to be satisfiable, and the interpretation/solution for `F_2` does not conflicts `F_1 and (not G)`. If that is not the case, Z3 can waste a lot of resources with `F_2`.

Comment: The unsat core would leave out `F_2`, yes? Obviously you get that after the fact (too late for OP, as written), but it may be useful for back-jumping for the caller of the SMT if these formulas are the result of a search.

Comment: Yes, a minimal unsat core would leave out `F_2`. However, we have to keep in mind that, in practice, "computing minimal unsat cores" is more expensive than "computing unsat cores" which is more expensive than "just checking satisfiability".